# Criando uma lista com sublistas em c++

Tags: c++

Estou tentando criar uma lista com as sublistas (20.0  20.0  0.0) (36.0  150.0 0.0) (200.0 130.0 0.0) (215.0 20.0  0.0) em C++ e gostaria de uma ajuda pois não sei como juntar as 4 para formar uma lista. Eu preciso de algo como append em LISP.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<double> reals_list;

int main()
{
    std::vector<reals_list> list_of_lists;

    list_of_lists.push_back({20.0, 20.0, 0.0});
    list_of_lists.push_back({36.0, 150.0, 0.0});
    list_of_lists.push_back({200.0, 130.0, 0.0});
    list_of_lists.push_back({215.0, 20.0, 0.0});

    std::cout << list_of_lists[3][0]
        << ", " << list_of_lists[3][1]
        << ", " << list_of_lists[3][2] << std::endl;
}
```

Não pude deixar de notar que a lista interna sempre tem 3 elementos. Se for o caso, recomendo criar uma classe ou estrutura de tramanho fixo, que tem uma performance muito melhor que o `std::vector`, que é um vetor genérico de tamanho arbitrário. Exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Vector3 {
    double x, y, z;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Vector3> list_of_lists;

    list_of_lists.push_back({20.0, 20.0, 0.0});
    list_of_lists.push_back({36.0, 150.0, 0.0});
    list_of_lists.push_back({200.0, 130.0, 0.0});
    list_of_lists.push_back({215.0, 20.0, 0.0});

    std::cout << list_of_lists[3].x
        << ", " << list_of_lists[3].y
        << ", " << list_of_lists[3].z << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Nem me liguei de falar antes, mas no caso eu estou fazendo esse programa usando a biblioteca FDT para programar em um CAD.

Comment: Não conheço. Não sei como essa informação afetaria minha resposta.